# Pairing two mirror tables that each have "holes" in them

Tags: libreoffice

**I have two sets of data, each with cells sharing the same initial sequence of characters that could be used to pair them** (i.e. *entry from one dataset is a translation of the entry in the second dataset*).

However, **some entries do not have their complementary entry in the other dataset and vice versa**, which means that even if I alphabetically sort both of them and put side-by-side, they will not be completely mirroring each other.
How could I pair them and leave empty rows where one entry doesn't have its sibling on the other side?

[image: annotated files side by side]

P.S Manual editing is out of the question, unfortunately. It's over 1000 rows.

P.P.S I've tried AskLibre, but I got no help :(

P.P.S I'm using LibreOffice 6.3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

1) Create 2 helper columns containing the shared term split out from each of the two columns. Here is an example that uses data in column A and the separator being ^ instead of a bullet

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("^",A1)-1)
```

2) Find the matches uses index(match()). This assumes your data columns are A and C and your helper columns are B and D.

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(B1,$D$1:$D$5,0))
```

3) (Optional) Non-matches will show as #N/A. If you want you can handle that by surrounding the index(match()) with the following to make the non-matches blank cells

```
=IFERROR(<formula from 2>, "")
```

Possible Error Handling: It looks like your data may contain whitespace. If the index(match()) isn't returning a bunch of matches then it is likely due to mismatching whitespace. To handle this you can surround the formulas from part 1 in the following to remove both leading and trailing whitespace

```
=TRIM(<formula from 1>)
```

(Solution provided by **FleetAdmiralFader** [link to OP](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/dsese0/pairing_two_datasets_that_share_the_same_initial/f6plool/?st=k2nvd9pt&sh=c1eafdda))